# How to find the optimal classifier for a given loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, bayes-optimal-classifier

For a binary classification problem (labels being 0 and 1) and a classifier $g$ we consider the loss function $L(g)=P[Y\neq g(X)]$. It is known that the optimal classifier $g^*$ that minimizes $L$ is $g(x) = I_{P(Y=1|X=x)>\frac{1}{2}}$.

If we define $\hat{L}(g)=L(g) +c P[g(X)=1]$, where $c\in[0,1]$ :

- What would be the upside of such a cost function ?
- What's the optimal Bayes classifier for this cost function ? More broadly speaking, when given some *customized* loss function, how should one proceed to find the optimal classifier associated to that function ?

For the first question, it seems to be that it would be in classification problems where we only want to predict the positive class if we're very confident that it's indeed positive. Is that correct ?

Thank you.

Comment: A couple things. 1) It's not true in general that naive Bayes is the optimal classifier under the 0/1 loss. Did you mean that this is 'known' in the sense that we're to assume it's true for this particular problem? 2) Is this coursework? If so, please add the self-study tag and have a look at its wiki.

Comment: 1) I edited my question. I shouldn't have used the term "Naive Bayes". Hope it's clearer now. 2) It is not. A friend and I came across this while reviewing some basics in Statistical Learning & complexity inequalities and couldn't quite figure out how to deal with such cost functions.